# Angular 4 to 5: Error:error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void | LineSideInspection>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<LineSideInspection>'

Tags: angular, typescript

It was working fine with Angular 4. Now I upgraded to 5.0. Now I am getting the below error. The entire project( in Angular 4) is in github. https://github.com/SudhirSahoo/IQS

```
ERROR in src/app/lineside-inspection/lineside-inspection.service.ts(44,9): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void | LineSideInspection>' is not assigna
ble to type 'Promise<LineSideInspection>'.
  Type 'void | LineSideInspection' is not assignable to type 'LineSideInspection'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'LineSideInspection'.
src/app/lineside-inspection/lineside-inspection.service.ts(50,64): error TS2339: Property 'rankAcount' does not exist on type 'Response'.
src/app/lineside-inspection/lineside-inspection.service.ts(51,64): error TS2339: Property 'rankBcount' does not exist on type 'Response'.
src/app/lineside-inspection/lineside-inspection.service.ts(52,64): error TS2339: Property 'rankCcount' does not exist on type 'Response'.
src/app/lineside-inspection/lineside-inspection.service.ts(54,24): error TS2352: Type 'Response' cannot be converted to type 'LineSideInspection'
.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Response'.
```

Code:

```
update(inspection: LineSideInspection): Promise<LineSideInspection> {
        const url = '/api/inspection/updatecount/';
        let rankName = inspection.rankName;
        return this.http
            .post(url, JSON.stringify(inspection), {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                let data = response.json();
                if (rankName='A') inspection.rankAcount = data.rankAcount;
                if (rankName='B') inspection.rankBcount = data.rankBcount;
                if (rankName='C') inspection.rankCcount = data.rankCcount;
                return response.json() as LineSideInspection;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert("error");
            });
    }
```

If I change the return type to any, then I am not getting that error while ng build.

```
update(inspection: LineSideInspection): any {
        const url = '/api/inspection/updatecount/';
        let rankName = inspection.rankName;
        return this.http
```

But I really have to change the return type everywhere?

Comment: Hey please explain why downvote. That makes others not to even see the question...

Answer (score 1):

It is because your catch block returns void. You have two options.

First is to remove the catch block from your update method and handle the errors elsewhere.

```
update(inspection: LineSideInspection): Promise < LineSideInspection > {
  const url = '/api/inspection/updatecount/';
  let rankName = inspection.rankName;
  return this.http
    .post(url, JSON.stringify(inspection), {
      headers: this.headers
    })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      let data = response.json();
      if (rankName = 'A') inspection.rankAcount = data.rankAcount;
      if (rankName = 'B') inspection.rankBcount = data.rankBcount;
      if (rankName = 'C') inspection.rankCcount = data.rankCcount;
      return response.json() as LineSideInspection;
    })
    // .catch(error => {
    //  alert("error");
    // });
}
```

Second, is to return an object that meets the LineSideInspection from the `catch` operator.

```js
import { of
} from 'rxjs/observable/of';

update(inspection: LineSideInspection): Promise < LineSideInspection > {
  const url = '/api/inspection/updatecount/';
  let rankName = inspection.rankName;
  return this.http
    .post(url, JSON.stringify(inspection), {
      headers: this.headers
    })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      let data = response.json();
      if (rankName = 'A') inspection.rankAcount = data.rankAcount;
      if (rankName = 'B') inspection.rankBcount = data.rankBcount;
      if (rankName = 'C') inspection.rankCcount = data.rankCcount;
      return response.json() as LineSideInspection;
    })
    .catch(error => of({} as LineSideInspection))
}
```